# Elastic net in glmnet vs CVXR

Tags: r, optimization, lasso, ridge-regression, glmnet

I'm attempting to match some simple results in R using glmnet and CVXR and coming up a little short.

Using the data from the 'QuickStartExample' in glmnet I run, for ridge:

```
fit = glmnet(x, y, intercept=F, standardize=F, lambda=1, alpha=0)
```

which gives me one set of coefficients and the objective function value `2.559086` from

```
coefs = coef(fit)
m = length(y)
sum((y - (x %*% coefs[-1]))^2)/(2*m) + 1 * sum(coefs[-1]^2) * .5
```

When I run the CVXR code (taken from section 3.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07582.pdf)):

```
beta = Variable(20)
elastic_reg <- function(beta, lambda = 0, alpha = 0) {
   ridge <- (1 - alpha) * sum(beta^2) * .5
   lasso <- alpha * p_norm(beta, 1)
   lambda * (lasso + ridge)
}
 loss <- sum((y - x %*% beta)^2)/(2*m)
 obj <- loss + elastic_reg(beta, 1, 0)
 prob <- Problem(Minimize(obj))
 result <- solve(prob)
 result$value
```

I get the objective `2.859259` and a somewhat different set of coefficients.  I get a similar mismatch with lasso.

Can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that the two libraries are finding slightly different optima that are effectively the same. What happens if you plot the coefficients against one another? Do they fall very near the 1:1 line?

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  They form a pretty straight line (R^2 around .98) , but with a slope of about two, or .5, rather than one.  It's too bad that, as far as I know, it's not possible to set custom starting values for the optimization in either library.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to compare glmnet results to CVXR for the gaussian case, standardize your response as the documentation for glmnet clearly advises. (Note also that glmnet uses n rather than n-1 in the denominator for y.) This will ensure that the lambda is on the same scale as shown below.

Here is your example showing that the results are quite the same.

```
> suppressMessages(library(glmnet))
> data(QuickStartExample)
> catn <- function(...) cat(..., "\n")
> objective_value <- function(y, x, coefs, lambda, alpha) {
+     n <- nrow(x)
+     ridge <- sum(coefs^2) ; l1 <- sum(abs(coefs))
+     sum((y - (x %*% coefs))^2) / (2 * n) + lambda * ((1 - alpha) / 2 * ridge + alpha * l1)
+ }
> lambda <- 1 ; alpha <- 0
> y_s <- local({
+     n <- length(y)
+     m <- mean(y); s <- as.numeric(sqrt(var(y) * (n - 1) / n));
+     result <- (y - m) / s ## scale using 1/n
+     attr(result, "scaled:center") <- m
+     attr(result, "scaled:scale") <- s
+     result
+ })
> ## STANDARDIZED COMPARISON
> fit_s <- glmnet(x, y_s, intercept=F, standardize=F, lambda = lambda, alpha=alpha)
> catn("Glmnet objective (scaled y)",
+     objective_value(y_s, x, coef(fit_s)[-1], lambda, alpha))
Glmnet objective (scaled y) 0.2504412 

> suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(CVXR)))
> beta <- Variable(20)
> elastic_reg <- function(beta, lambda = 0, alpha = 0) {
+     ridge <- (1 - alpha) / 2 * sum_squares(beta)
+     lasso <- alpha * p_norm(beta, 1)
+     lambda * (lasso + ridge)
+ }
> loss <- sum((y_s - x %*% beta)^2) / ( 2 * nrow(x))
> obj <- loss + elastic_reg(beta, lambda = lambda, alpha)
> prob <- Problem(Minimize(obj))
> betaHat0 <- solve(prob)$getValue(beta)
> catn("CVXR objective (scaled y):", objective_value(y_s, x, betaHat0, lambda, alpha))
CVXR objective (scaled y): 0.2504412 

> > ## NONSTANDARDIZED COMPARISON
> fit <- glmnet(x, y, intercept=F, standardize=F, lambda = lambda, alpha=alpha)
> catn("Glmnet objective (unscaled y)", objective_value(y, x, coef(fit)[-1], lambda, alpha))
Glmnet objective (unscaled y) 2.559086 

> loss <- sum((y - x %*% beta)^2) / ( 2 * nrow(x))
> obj <- loss + elastic_reg(beta, lambda = lambda / attr(y_s, "scaled:scale"), alpha)
> prob <- Problem(Minimize(obj))
> betaHat <- solve(prob)$getValue(beta)
> catn("CVXR objective (unscaled y)", objective_value(y, x, betaHat, lambda, alpha))
CVXR objective (unscaled y) 2.559092 

> print(cbind(betaHat, coef(fit)[-1]))
              [,1]         [,2]
 [1,]  1.116973034  1.116966642
 [2,]  0.069758599  0.069748770
 [3,]  0.567502729  0.567498653
 [4,]  0.007165595  0.007143619
 [5,] -0.682552826 -0.682558269
 [6,]  0.537045911  0.537052521
 [7,]  0.121028093  0.121016831
 [8,]  0.301686483  0.301686360
 [9,] -0.074554572 -0.074549749
[10,]  0.053848167  0.053838499
[11,]  0.142725221  0.142732390
[12,] -0.072507453 -0.072493577
[13,] -0.028559087 -0.028567753
[14,] -0.931903020 -0.931895363
[15,] -0.076912214 -0.076906043
[16,]  0.018498330  0.018496310
[17,]  0.007939484  0.007940091
[18,]  0.009485041  0.009484634
[19,]  0.031093511  0.031094417
[20,] -0.784158196 -0.784162483
```